# SQL - combining consecutive months of the same block with same quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server

This question will seem very easy at first but as you start writing the complexity hits. I have attached a picture blow with the result set of my SQL. The result is 39 rows. I need to combine all the consecutive rows of the same block with the same value. With this example, the end result should be 29 rows where all the red box'd rows below should be consolidated into 1 row.

so for example the first redbox with quantity = 40 should combine into 1 row with term_start = 2017-06-01 and term_end = 2017-08-01

[image]

Here's my Code

```
SELECT
pp.position
, term_start = pq.begtime
, term_end = pq.endtime
, quantity = CONVERT(VARCHAR,convert(double precision, pq.energy))  
, block = p.block           
FROM trade t
   INNER JOIN position p on p.trade = t.trade
   INNER JOIN powerposition pp on p.position = pp.position
   INNER JOIN powerquantity pq on pq.position = pp.position 
        AND pq.posdetail = pp.posdetail 
        AND pq.quantitystatus = 'TRADE'
WHERE 1=1
AND p.positionmode = 'PHYSICAL'
AND t.collaboration = 13119572
```

I've been stuck on this problem for three days straight now. I've explored using CTEs and Row_Number() over () but with no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Doesn't make sense. think about `pp.position`. (After you do, the *simple* solution is to `group by`)

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag your question.  (I'm guessing Postgres.)

Comment: Which `position` and `block` values do you wish to return?

Comment: @sgeddes I only care about the term_start, term_end, and quantity rows. I need to combine consecutive dates with the same quantity. the only reason position and block values are present to show that I want the result in that order

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, I am running on sql server, is that what you're asking?

Comment: @Amit sorry I don't understand what you mean, the only reason I included position is to show this is the order I need the sql result set to be in. Because I need consecutive rows with the same quantity to combine, it wouldn't work if the result set wasn't in ascending order of position

Comment: Your code selects `pp.position`. Take a paper & a pen, and write down the output you want to generate. Don't forget this column.

Comment: Interesting.  I associate `double precision` with Postgres.  SQL Server people usually use `float` (in my experience), but `double precision` is super acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for consecutive values.  Here is one way, using a difference of row numbers to identify a group:

```
with t as (<your query here>)
select min(term_start), max(term_end), block, quantity
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by block order by position) -
              row_number() over (partition by quantity, block order by position)
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by quantity, grp, block;
```

Comment: Thanks!! This works if I add order by block, term_start at the end. The only downside is it's not in the order the original result set is in, but now it's sorted by block first. However it should still work!

Comment: @Jack89515 . . . You can add `order by min(position)`.